# is there a way to get on-premises sid for Azure hybrid joined device in Microsoft graph?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to get the on-premises Security Identifier (SID) for hybrid joined devices, I have tried going through Microsoft Graph Documentation but I can only find the User SID, is there a way to also do it for computers?

Answer (score 0):

After much Googling, a colleague pointed out that it is only available in the beta API.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/device?view=graph-rest-beta